# Unable to hit Rest Api in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have a Spring Boot application, that runs on port(s): 8082.
This is the definition of my Controller :

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PREFIX)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChangeRequestController {
 public static final String PREFIX = "/api/project/v1/changes";
 private final ChangeRequestService changeRequestService;

 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
 @RequestMapping(value = "/raiseNewCR")
 public void createChangeRequest(@RequestBody ChangeRequestDto changeRequestDto, HttpServletRequest 
                                  req, HttpServletResponse resp){
    changeRequestService.createChangeRequest(changeRequestDto);
 }
}
```

I have tried to post via Postman to this url: http://localhost:8082/api/project/v1/changes/raiseNewCR
However the value that is returned is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-02-17T14:16:43.699+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/"
}
```

I don't know where I went wrong, can someone tell me how to overcome this problem? Please Assist

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are not supposed to return void since you are posting, instead you should return your `ResponseEntity`.

Secondly, I do not see where you mentioned that it's a post request in your code. I thought you were supposed to include `@PostMapping` annotation on your controller there.

Comment: I thought the /@RequestMapping annotation would be enough. I will try to use 
 /@PostMapping. Also, you said I must use ResponseEntity, is it suppose to be ResponseEntity<?>

Comment: exactly its  public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse<ChangeRequestDto>> createChangeRequest(@RequestBody .........)